# What is the meaning of the verb ‘betreiben’ in a renting application?

Tags: meaning, swiss-standard-german

I’m filling in a renting application for a flat.
There is one question:

> «Wurden Sie schon betrieben?» — Ja/Nein

I can’t figure out what it means in this case. Perhaps it is Switzerland-specific, and I believe it is asking if I was ever in debt?

Comment: According to this [definition of "Betreibung"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betreibung) you seem to be quite close. It is specific to Switzerland and it means that you failed to pay your debt in time.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh. So in this case, since I have never failed to pay my debt in time, I should answer with 'Nein', correct?

Comment: Yes. I think no one would be allowed to ask (or at least expect a true answer) whether you had any debts before. I didn't check complete text but "Zwangsvollstreckung" is about collecting the money someone should have paid earlier. I think this also applies to situations where you run a business and this business is bancrupt etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Swiss German. If you owe money to someone (let's say to a bank), and you failed to pay, then the creditor (here: the bank) can call a lawyer to recover the money.

In all regions you can say:

> Die Bank treibt Geld von Herrn Huber ein.
>   The bank recovers money from Mr. Huber.

In Swiss German you also can say:

> Herr Huber wird von der Bank betrieben.

Comment: Wenn das Geschäft/Restaurant/etc. von mir betrieben wird, bin ich dann der Geschäftsführer, oder ein Gläubiger?

Comment: @Gerhardh: In der Schweiz könntest du beides sein, in Österreich und Deutschland nur Geschäftsführer.

Comment: Danke. Dass die deutsche Sprache viele Mehrdeutigkeiten erlaubt, ist ja nicht neu. Mir fällt gerade keine andere ein, wo die möglichen Bedeutungen weiter auseinander liegen: Ein erfolgreich betriebenes Restaurant läuft also entweder gut, oder es ist fast pleite. Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Das Deutsche kennt aber Wörter, die zwei genau gegenteilige Bedeutungen haben können, z.B. »abdecken« (etwas darauf legen: »Ich habe das Loch *abgedeckt*, damit keiner reinfallen kann« oder eine Abdeckung entfernen: »Der Sturm hat alle Häuser *abgedeckt*, die Dachschindeln liegen jetzt auf der Straße.«) oder »Platzangst« (umgangssprachlich: Angst vor engen Räumen (Klaustrophobie); fachsprachlich: Angst vor großen Plätzen (Agoraphobie)) oder auch »Untiefe« (Stelle in einem Gewässer, die je nach Kontext besonders tief oder besonders seicht ist). Man nennt solche Wörter »Januswörter«.